# MIPS Check if equal to a certain character

Tags: ascii, mips

I am trying to write sprinf in mips. First, I am trying to count how many characters there are.

```
sprintf:
    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 8($sp)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
    sw $s2, 0($sp)




        li      $s0, 0          # len = 1
        la      $s1, ($a1)        # s = str
test:
        lb      $s2, 0($s1)     # c = *s
        beqz    $s2, done       # if c == '\0', branch to "done"
        beq $s2, '5', done
        addi    $s0, $s0, 1     # len = len + 1
        addi    $s1, $s1, 1     # s = s + 1
        j       test

percent:




done:
        li      $v0, 1          # syscall code: print_int
        move    $a0, $s0
        syscall
        li      $v0, 11         # syscall code: print_char
        li      $a0, 10         # pass newline character
        syscall

        jr      $ra
```

But there will be a need to check if in the format when there is a %d, or %c ,etc.

How do I check for a certain character like that?
I saw this for mips ascii 
http://galia.fc.uaslp.mx/~luis/arquitectura_files/table.pdf

but what would the beq look like?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to consult an ASCII table. Any assembler worth using supports character immediates. So you can do:

```
lbu $s2,($s1)
li $t0,'%'
bne $s2,$t0,not_percent_sign
```

Or if your assembler supports branch pseduo-instructions with immediates:

```
lbu $s2,($s1)
bne $s2,'%',not_percent_sign
```